# Create SharePoint Organizational Chart in a different way

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, organization-browser, visio-services

I would like to know how is it possible to make a organizational Chart-Browser as shown in the image attached, in SharePoint 2013?[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use Visio and Visio Services.  Visio already has a org chart templates that can link to data sources and import pictures from exchange (if desired).

there are open API's available that can also be used.  You can embed thse in SharePoint pages. for Example, Google has one here:  https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/orgchart

There are also a few 3rd party tools that have webparts available.

Comment: Finally I made an app(SP On Premise) and for the moment i use a dummy list of users which in the parent site(a manager field is used to find the tree) and with the use of KineticJS. This is working for the moment... But i would like to get details of the users from the User Profile Service or similar... could you please direct me where and how can i get that info?

Comment: @Betsen You can leverage CSOM or REST.  Don't query the profile service directly, use search instead  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nadeemis/archive/2012/08/24/sharepoint-2013-search-rest-api.aspx  -HTH